# PHP filter bad words

Tags: php

I have a filter bad words codes below
I want to replace this ARRAY with the .txt file so that I can put all the bad words into the txt file or is there any way to use MYSQL database to store the badwords and then call from there ?

```
FUNCTION BadWordFilter(&$text, $replace){

 $bads = ARRAY (
      ARRAY("butt","b***"),
      ARRAY("poop","p***"),
      ARRAY("crap","c***")
 );

 IF($replace==1) {                                        //we are replacing
      $remember = $text;

      FOR($i=0;$i<sizeof($bads);$i++) {               //go through each bad word
           $text = EREGI_REPLACE($bads[$i][0],$bads[$i][1],$text); //replace it
      }

      IF($remember!=$text) RETURN 1;                     //if there are any changes, return 1

 } ELSE {                                                  //we are just checking

      FOR($i=0;$i<sizeof($bads);$i++) {               //go through each bad word
           IF(EREGI($bads[$i][0],$text)) RETURN 1; //if we find any, return 1
      }     
 }
}

$qtitle = BadWordFilter($wordsToFilter,1);
```

Comment: yes, both txt and db is possible. what's your question? what's the problem?

Comment: I sense a [clbuttic mistake](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx), or in this case, a [censored b***erfly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) in the making

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes make a file like bad_words.txt with entries like (note each word combo is on a separate line):

```
butt,b***
poop,p***
crap,c***
```

Then read that file into an array like so:

```
$file_array = file('/path/to/bad_word.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Then to create an array like your $bads array do this:

```
$bads = array();
foreach ($file_array as $word_combo) {
    $bads[] = explode(',', $word_combo);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This actually doesn't work, you need to use file('/path/to/bad_word.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); if you want each line to be recognized correctly. Especially if you directly work with strings only.

Answer (score 4):

I just developed a function that can filter out the bad words

```
function hate_bad($str)
{
    $bad = array("shit","ass");
    $piece = explode(" ",$str);
    for($i=0; $i < sizeof($bad); $i++)
    {
        for($j=0; $j < sizeof($piece); $j++)
        {
            if($bad[$i] == $piece[$j])
            {
                $piece[$j] = " ***** ";
            }
        }
    }

    return $piece;
}
```

and call it like this

```
$str = $_REQUEST['bad']; //'bad' is the name of the text field here
$good = hate_bad($str);   

if(isset($_REQUEST['filter'])) //'filter' is the name of button
{
    for($i=0; $i < sizeof($good); $i++)
    {
        echo $good[$i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do either...

You can use something like `file_get_contents()` to read in from a file, or use a [MySQL API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) to  query your database for bad words.

Do you have a database schema set up? Also, `eregi_replace()` is deprecated. Use `preg_replace()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use MYSQL.

Just have a table with two columns: the word and the replacement.

Then in your code, you will need to connect to the database and read in each row. But you can then store each row in an array.

The result would be very similar to your current array structure.

To connect to a database, use the tutorial below.
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php13p1.html