# Inserted Malicious content

Tags: php, laravel, invisible-recaptcha

I have laravel application which having some forms that end user can fill,
the forms also protected by google invisible captcha.

but after some time i am getting some malicious records to be inserted via forms, some dirty words.unrelated content just like,

> Viagra Extra Dose Amoxicillin Bronchitis Dosage Cephalexin And Side Effects In Children buy generic cialis Prix Viagra 25 Milligrams Achat Viagra Paris Cialis Prezzo Controindicazioni

How can i prevent this, how can i avoid user to insert those dirty words.
please suggest.

Comment: Look at adding a honeypot field: https://dev.to/felipperegazio/how-to-create-a-simple-honeypot-to-protect-your-web-forms-from-spammers--25n8

Comment: Use some sort of CAPTCHA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent robots from automatically filling up a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387496/how-to-prevent-robots-from-automatically-filling-up-a-form)

Comment: hi @user3783243 thanks for reply. please try to understand what my question is, then after mark it as duplicate. its not duplicate bro.. please check i have mentioned that i am already using google's invisible captcha, and i know it prevents bot attach,
but my question is i am receiving some disgusting contents from end user.
how can i restrict user to insert that type of content.

Comment: That is a bot, I suspect your CAPTCHA is not configured correctly. If you are just asking how to implement a black list there are tens of thousands of tutorials that demonstrate that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549197/php-form-curse-word-input-filter-solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523742/php-filter-bad-words https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273516/how-do-you-implement-a-good-profanity-filter

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the only thing you can do is to blacklist specific words. You can use this https://www.freewebheaders.com/full-list-of-bad-words-banned-by-google/ blacklist for example and foreach over it and

`if(str_pos($user_input, $current_blacklist_word)){
   //show Error 
}`

Comment: `strpos` usage is incorrect and this is wrong. There is more that can be done. Also you should read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem